# replace row values with row values from another column if conditions met

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I would like to replace row values in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'type': ['place', 'home', 'place', 'walk', 'place', 'work', 'home', 'place'],'labels': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'shop', 'Nan', 'clinic', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN']}
a = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['type', 'labels'])
```

Is there some possibilities to replace  a['type'] with a['labels'] only the conditions if a['labels'] is not np.NaN and a['type'] == 'place' using pandas?

I would prefer to use df.loc[] if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the data you provided isn't actually `np.NaN`, it's just the string `'NaN'` or `'Nan'` which are handled differently. If that is your starting point you can do:

```
a['labels'] = a['labels'].str.lower().replace('nan', np.NaN)
```

Then define your `mask` and replace:

```
mask = (a['labels'].notnull()) & (a['type'] == 'place') 
df.loc[mask, 'type'] = df.loc[mask, 'labels']

     type  labels
0   place     NaN
1    home     NaN
2    shop    shop
3    walk     NaN
4  clinic  clinic
5    work     NaN
6    home     NaN
7   place     NaN
```

Alternatively, with the same `mask` defined above you can use `numpy.where`

```
a['type'] = np.where(mask, a['labels'], a['type'])
```

Comment: you are the best